# Dynamic distinct values using Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

I was unsure if what I wrote as a Title would suffice, but I will do my best to explain what I am trying to accomplish here:

I am trying to recreate this query that I use to look up distinct data from `TestColumn`:

```
 List<string> groupQuery = (from p in testDepo
                                      group p by new { p.TestColumn}
                                      into distinctTest
                                      select distinctTest.First().TestColumn).ToList();
```

But instead of statically call `TestColumn`. I would like to dynamically pass in the name: `TestColumn` into a variable and then do my distinct value query using the variable name.

So far I have this:

```
string primaryColumn = "TestColumn"
List<string> groupQuery= (from p in testDepo
                                    group p by new { primaryColumn }
                                    into distinctTest
                                    select distinctTest.First().GetType().GetProperty(primaryColumn).GetValue(distinctTest.First()).ToString()).ToList();
```

I know i am probably doing something silly, but i cant quite wrap my head around it right now. my dynamic query only half works. It is only getting the first distict value, but not the rest of them. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What is the type of `p` in your query?

Comment: `p` is the object that i am trying get distinct values from.

Comment: Yes, but what is the type of that object?

Comment: Like my entity model that is connected to my database to a table called `Test`

Comment: Nice coincidence, I just named the test class in my code `Test` just like your table name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `Func` from an `Expression` using your property column string like this:

```
var primaryColumn = "TestColumn";
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Test), "p");
var col = Expression.Property(param, primaryColumn);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(col, param);
var func = lambda.Compile();
```

Then use it in your query like this:

```
List<string> groupQuery= (from p in testDepo
                          group p by func.DynamicInvoke(p)
                          into distinctTest
                          select distinctTest.First()
                                             .GetType()
                                             .GetProperty(primaryColumn)
                                             .GetValue(distinctTest.First())
                                             .ToString()
                          ).ToList()
```

Comment: for `var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Test), "p");` i would not be able to use `p` since it is already being used in my query. Would i have to change both the variable name and the string name? or just the variable name?

Comment: Change just the variable name. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What is TestDepro?  You need to be able to return the column by name something like p[primaryColumn].